# Is every conformal diffeomorphism isotop (or homotop) to an isometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, homotopy-theory, conformal-geometry

Assume that $M$ is  a  compact simply  connected Riemannian manifold and  $f$ is a  conformal  diffeomeorphism of  $M$. Is it true  to  say that  $f$ is  homotopic (or  isotopic) to  an  isometry of  $M$?

What would  be the  answer  if  we drop the  simply  connected assumption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that this can be true in the form you state it. The point is that you can replace the given metric on $M$ by any conformal rescaling without changing the the conformal diffeomorphisms. However, a generic conformal rescaling of a given metric on $M$ should not admit any isometries. So you would end up with the statement that any conformal diffeomorphism is homotopic to the identity.

Comment: Thank you for  your answer. What is  an  explicit example  of  a simply  connected   Riemannian  manifold $M$ with trivial isometry but $M$ possess a  conformal  diffeomorphism not homotopic to identity?

Comment: If you are just looking for an explicit manifold, you can take an even dimensional sphere $S^{2n}$. Now take a smooth function $f:S^{2n}\to\mathbb R$ and define $g:=e^fg_0$, where $g_0$ is the round metric. Then any conformal transformation for $g_0$ is a conformal transformation for $g$. So in particular, the antipodal map is conformal and not homotopic to the identity. If $f$ is sufficiently generic, then $g$ will not have any isometries.

Comment: What  would be the answer if  we change the  question as follows: Is every orientation preserving diffeomorphism  homotopic to  a  conformal diffeomorphism.

Comment: This is a completely different quesiton, since it compares diffeomorphisms to conformal diffeomorphisms rather than conformal diffeomorphisms to isometries.  I don't known the answer, but generic conformal classes don't have conformal diffeomorphisms apart from the identity.

Answer (score 1):

It is known that if the group of conformal transformation of a compact manifold is compact, then it is conjugate to a group of isometries, and if it is not compact, then the manifolds is the sphere with its standard conformal structure (Lelong-Ferrand Obata).

Assume that the manifold is not conformal to the sphere, then any conformal map is an isometry of another metric conformal to the first one. But perhaps the manifod has no isometry at all ; for instance it is easy to construct a metric on the 2-sphere with no isometry, but this metric has a lot of conformal maps.

In the case the manifold is (conformal to) the sphere, the group of conformal transformations is the Möbius group which contains the groups of isometries as a retract, so every conformal transformation is isotopic to an isometry.

Comment: thank you for your  answer. What is  that metric  on $S^2$ and  what  is  a  conformal  diffeomorphism (of course of  degree $-1$) which is not  homotop  to the  identity?

Comment: Take a metric $g$ on the sphere without isometries (the boundary of a potatoe does the job). This metric is conformal to the standard one $g_0$, let $F$ be the  conformal  transformation $g\to g_0$, and  $C$ is any conformal map of the standard sphere.  Then $F^{-1}\circ C \circ F$  is a conformal transformation of $g$. If $C$ is of degree $-1$, yo have your example.